# Excluding ProvidePlugin from an entry point

Tags: webpack

Is there a way to tell the ProvidePlugin to not operate on a particular entry_point?

The use case is that I am using the Provide Plugin to give `$` to the entry points but there is a legacy part of the app that uses an older version of jquery because it relies on older dependencies and I can't seem to figure out how not to get the ProvidePlugin from clobbering that older version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly; you need to handle it a different way. If your `webpack.config.js` file exports an array of build config objects instead of a single config object, webpack will automatically do a build for each config. So you want to do separate builds, one for legacy and one for the rest (or maybe you'll end up doing more than two builds depending on your needs). In one config you include the ProvidePlugin, in another you don't.

My project has a large number of builds, so my config file loops through a number of relevant factors and creates multiple build config objects that get pushed into the exported array -- it's easy for them to share config this way, and the parts that need to vary between builds get wrapped in conditionals.

Comment: how did you get your manifest file to not overwrite itself? The multi mode compile works but the manifest file only shows one package

Comment: Sorry this is probably a separate issue with https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-manifest-plugin that I have to figure out. It mentions it briefly but I'm struggling to get it to work. Bascially in multi compile mode the manifest generated for each compile gets overwritten. It says there is a way for it to share but I haven't figured it out yet. I appreciate your help though!